# Send email on due date of invoice object

Tags: workflow

I have a custom object with a Due_Date__c field and an Email__c field. When the due date is hit, the system should send an email to the email listed in the Email__c field. The email will include some other information from this object too.

I'm guessing the right way for this would be to use a time-based workflow rule. However, I've been asked to use the process builder to accomplish this. What is the correct way to accomplish this requirement?

EDIT: We may have to add email addresses to send to from another object. I guess that would be something we can't accomplish using workflow rules?

Answer (score 0):

How about write a trigger on the custom object. after update, when the Due_Date__c equals date needed. Send the email to the Email__c field.

sorry. I didn't catch the part that you were asked to use the process builder for the task. i'm not sure what that is.

oops. bad advice. i came on here looking for answers to another question and saw nobody commented. kinda stuck my foot in my mouth. yeah the user would have to update the record. not what you need.

Comment: The trigger only fires when a user updates the record. The user would need to update the record on the due date for that to work